# Combine multiple dfs based on datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dfs

```
Date         x  y                 
2021-07-01  1  2
2021-07-02  2  4
2021-07-06  3  6
2021-07-07  4  8
2021-07-08  5  10

Date    z   n
2021-07-06  5  10
2021-07-07  6  12
2021-07-08  7  14
```

How Can I combine them based on the date so that I get. I have a fair few dfs to combine using an iterative process.

```
Date         x  y  z  n           
2021-07-01  1  2  nan  nan          
2021-07-02  2  4  nan  nan
2021-07-06  3  6  5  10
2021-07-07  4  8  6  12
2021-07-08  5  10  7  14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge`:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date', how='outer')
         Date  x   y    z     n
0  2021-07-01  1   2  NaN   NaN
1  2021-07-02  2   4  NaN   NaN
2  2021-07-06  3   6  5.0  10.0
3  2021-07-07  4   8  6.0  12.0
4  2021-07-08  5  10  7.0  14.0
```

Comment: Thanks I actually had tried this earlier but didnt notice an error in my code where i had put tempDF = df = pd.read_csv which was casuing it not to work

Answer (score 2):

Use given there are "a fair few dfs to combine" use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on `axis=1`, but use a list comprehension with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) to ensure correct alignment with the `Date` column:

```
# dfs is a list of DataFrames
df = pd.concat([f.set_index('Date') for f in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Or [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) can also be used with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
from functools import reduce


# dfs is a list of DataFrames
df = reduce(lambda a, b: pd.merge(a, b, on='Date', how='outer'), dfs)
```

`df`:

```
         Date  x   y    z     n
0  2021-07-01  1   2  NaN   NaN
1  2021-07-02  2   4  NaN   NaN
2  2021-07-06  3   6  5.0  10.0
3  2021-07-07  4   8  6.0  12.0
4  2021-07-08  5  10  7.0  14.0
```

---

Sample DataFrames and imports:

```
from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2021-07-01', '2021-07-02', '2021-07-06', '2021-07-07',
             '2021-07-08'],
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'y': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2021-07-06', '2021-07-07', '2021-07-08'], 'z': [5, 6, 7],
    'n': [10, 12, 14]
})

dfs = [df1, df2]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like concat

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns = ['Date','x','y'])
b = pd.DataFrame([[1,7,9],[3,8,2]],columns = ['Date','z','n'])
final = pd.concat([a,b])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a "fair few" number of data frames, it's better to combine the merge operation with a reduce.

This solution uses `merge` and `partial` from the `functools` module to combine an iterable of `DataFrames`, each having a `Date` column.  I assume you wanted to keep the `Date` index preserved, and `merge` will do this.

```py
import functools
merge_outer=functools.partial(pd.merge, how="outer", on="Date")
df = functools.reduce(merge_outer, [df1, df2, df3])
```